# Rename root user's home directory in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu

After viewing previous answers I followed the same thing for changing root user name by-

```
usermod -l New_username -m -d /home/New_username Old_username
```

But it is shown as-

```
usermod: user Old_username is currently used by process 1794
```

What is that and how can it be solved?
Please help me to change my username..it is misspelt and I want to change it

Comment: But your user is not the root user. I strongly recommend you to leave everything belonging to root as it is!

Comment: Don't show us "generic" commends, show the ones you actually used - AND tell us about what user you are talking.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'ps' to find out what PID 1794 is.  You can't do this if you're logged in as the user in question.  You could create another user, log in as them, and su to root, or reboot to single-user mode.